# Cannot download .kmz file extension file - due to extension configuration

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Error screeshot

[image: img]

Here is the code that I am using

```
var pdfPath = $('#urlHiddenField').val() + "Documents/UserSignedAgreements/" + encodeURIComponent(data);
window.open(pdfPath, '_blank');
```

What I am doing is getting the filename from database and file is saved on project folder. My all types of document type (jpg, png, txt, docx, pdf..etc) all are working, BUT FILE TYPE (.kmz) extension is not working.

There is an option on UI with the filename to click it and in new tab some documents get open while some get downloaded with above code. Need help how to go with this file extension.

Comment: You have to define a mime type in IIS for this, https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18439/download-link-for-custom-file-type

Comment: Thanks,

<configuration>

  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".kml" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".kml" mimeType="application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml" />
      <remove fileExtension=".kmz" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".kmz" mimeType="application/vnd.google-earth.kmz" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>